# Derive an expression for the probability that there are k tasks that are half-done at the instant when exactly one task becomes completely done.

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-process

There are n tasks that are given to n processors. Each task has two
phases, and the time for each phase is given by an exponentially distributed random
variable with parameter 1. The times for all phases and for all tasks are independent.
We say that a task is half-done if it has finished one of its two phases.

(a) Derive an expression for the probability that there are k tasks that are half-done at
the instant when exactly one task becomes completely done.

(b) Derive an expression for the expected time until exactly one task becomes completely
done.

(M.U Prob. and Computing, 8.16)

If we say each n processor is different poisson process, then first one will be ${n \choose 1}{{n-1} \choose {k-1}}P_2(t)P_1(t)^{k-1}P_0(t)^{n-k}$ (in 1 processor, there will be 2 hits, in k-1,1 hit and in the rest, no hit).

Similarly, second part will be $\int_{t=0}^{\infty}t{n \choose 1}P_2(t) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{{n-1} \choose {i}}P_1(t)^iP_0(t)^{n-1-i} dt = \int_{t=0}^{\infty}ntP_2(t) (P_1(t) + P_0(t))^{n-1} dt$

Am I doing this correctly?